# Click event does nothing when triggered

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

When I trigger a `.click()` event in a non-headless mode in puppeteer, nothing happens, not even an error.. "non-headless mode so i could visually monitor what is being clicked"

```
const scraper = {
test: async () => {
        let browser, page;
        try {
            browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                headless: false,
                args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
            });
            page = await browser.newPage();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        try {
            await page.goto("https://www.betking.com/sports/s/eventOdds/1-840-841-0-0,1-1107-1108-0-0,1-835-3775-0-0,", {
                waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"
            });
            console.log("scraping, wait...");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("waiting....");
        try {
            await page.waitFor('.eventsWrapper');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err, err.response);
        }

        try {
            let oddsListData = await page.evaluate(async () => {
                let regionAreaContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.areaContainer.region .regionGroup > .regionAreas > div:first-child > .area:nth-child(5)');
                regionAreaContainer = Array.prototype.slice.call(regionAreaContainer);
                let t = []; //Used to monitor the element being clicked
                regionAreaContainer.forEach(async (region) => {
                    let dat = await region.querySelector('div');
                    dat.innerHTML === "GG/NG" ? t.push(dat.innerHTML) : false; //Used to confirm that the right element is being clicked
                    dat.innerHTML === "GG/NG" ? dat.click() : false;
                })
                return t;
            })
            console.log(oddsListData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to click the specified button and load in some dynamic data on the page.

In Chrome's console, I get the error

```
Transition Rejection($id: 1 type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different transition, detail: Transition#3( 'sportsMultipleEvents'{"eventMarketIds":"1-840-841-0-0,1-1107-1108-0-0,1-835-3775-0-0,"} -> 'sportsMultipleEvents'{"eventMarketIds":"1-840-841-0-0,1-1107-1108-0-0,1-835-3775-535-14,"} ))
```

Comment: What happens when you do that in chrome console?

Comment: In chrome's console, i get the error 
```
bower.js:79834 Transition Rejection($id: 1 type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different transition, detail: Transition#3( 'sportsMultipleEvents'{"eventMarketIds":"1-840-841-0-0,1-1107-1108-0-0,1-835-3775-0-0,"} -> 'sportsMultipleEvents'{"eventMarketIds":"1-840-841-0-0,1-1107-1108-0-0,1-835-3775-535-14,"} ))
```

Comment: It sounds like it's clicking them too fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

Behaving *non-human-like* by executing code like `element.click()` (inside the page context) or `element.value = '..'` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55560882/5627599) for a similar problem) seems to be problematic for Angular applications. You want to try to behave more *human-like* by using puppeteer functions like `page.click()` as they simulate a "real" mouse click instead of just triggering the element's click event.

In addition the page seems to rebuild parts of the page whenever one of the items is clicked. Therefore, you need to execute the selector again after each click.

#### Code sample

To behave more human-like and requery the elements after each click you can change the latter part of your code to something like this:

```js
let list = await page.$x("//div[div/text() = 'GG/NG']");
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    await list[i].click();

    // give the page some time and then query the selectors again
    await page.waitFor(500);
    list = await page.$x("//div[div/text() = 'GG/NG']");
}
```

This code uses an XPath expression to query the `div` elements which contain another `div` element with the given text. After that, a click is simulated on the element and then the contents of the page are queried another time to respect the change of the DOM elements.

Comment: I'm not sure, but could a page.evaluate() be nested in another page.evaluate()? I'm getting an error "page is not defined"

Comment: @Gbahdeyboh The code needs to be outside of a `page.evaluate`. You need to replace the code inside the last try block with it.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. I still get the same error in chrome's console 

"Transition Rejection($id: 1 type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different transition, detail: "null")"

Comment: This worked with the setTimeout @pguardiario suggested. But just the last div gets clicked. Not really sure of why that happens.

Comment: @Gbahdeyboh I added a `page.waitFor(100)` to my answer, does this help?

Comment: No, just the last one gets clicked. I increased the waiting time to 1000ms, still the same

Comment: @Gbahdeyboh Is the content maybe different to what you are checking? Does `oddsListData` actually contain more than one text?

Comment: Yes, oddListData contains three text's which is what i want.

Comment: @Gbahdeyboh Just noticed there was a typo in my code. You might have already noticed it (`element` -> `div`). Are you sure that the other divs are not clicked?

Comment: Yeah, i noticed it already. just didn't mention it. Yes, after the click, dynamic data is being loaded. Dynamic data is only loaded for the last div. It only loads dynamic data for other divs when i click them manually.

Comment: @Gbahdeyboh Well, maybe the event handlers are bound to an element inside the divs? I don't think I can help you more without seeing the actual code :-/

Comment: I created a github gist containing the code that replicates the problem, here's the link     

https://gist.github.com/Gbahdeyboh/3db36152378065ac674cf09d092f12f6

Comment: @Gbahdeyboh I found the problem. After each click, the page is rebuild, therefore you have to run the query again. I modified my code. Just replace the last try..catch block with this code and it should be working.

Comment: Thanks alot @Thomas . It works now. I think  i might have to look into Xpath expression. Came in handy there

Answer (score 1):

Here might be a less confusing way to click those:

```
for(var div of document.querySelectorAll('div')){
  if(div.innerHTML === 'GG/NG') div.click()
}
```

Comment: I get the same Error with this

Comment: It might still be too fast. If so you need to use a setTimeout

Comment: Yes! It's clicking too fast. When i setTimeout, only the last div  gets clicked. I'm not really sure of what might be causing it to skip the first two divs